# как отправить файл через curl на php

Tags: php, curl

как с помощью curl перепрошить камеру?

Инструкция

**Syntax** http:///cgi-bin/upgrader.cgi?action=uploadFirmware

**Method** POST

**Description**
Use this message to upload the firmware, and when the device receiving all the data successfully, it will start to upgrade the device, and then use the getState method to get the state.

**Example**

POST /cgi-bin/upgrader.cgi?action=uploadFirmware HTTP/1.1

Host: 192.168.1.108

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------8655433224198

Content-Length: xxxxxxxxx

-----------------------------8655433224198

Content-Disposition:form-data;name="upgrade"; filename= "xxxxxx.bin"

Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Firmware data . -----------------------------8655433224198--

мой код

```
 $postdata = array(
  'Host' => "127.0.0.1",
  'Connection'=> "keep-alive",
  'Content-Type'=> "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------8655433224198",
  'Content-Length'=> strlen($file),
  'Content-Disposition'=>'form-data;name="upgrade"; filename= "@xxx.bin"',
  'Content-Type'=> "application/octet-stream",
  'Firmware data' . "-----------------------------8655433224198--"
);




$options = array(
          CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
          CURLOPT_USERPWD        => $user . ":" . $pass,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 2,
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postdata,
          CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 4,
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Например вот так:

```
$ curl -X POST -d @fileName http://user:pass@host:port/path/toNeed/url
```

Comment: а что тогда значит Firmware data . -----------------------------8655433224198-- и Content-Length: xxxxxxxxx -----------------------------8655433224198 –

Comment: А размер какой у файла?

Comment: (20 613 159 байт)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте следующий вариант.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------8655433224198" -F "data=@xxxxxx.bin" -H "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upgrade\"; filename=\"xxxxxx.bin\"" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" "https://.../cgi-bin/upgrader.cgi?action=uploadFirmware/" -v
```

Для вывода лога используется ключ `-v`.

Comment: а что тогда значит Firmware data . -----------------------------8655433224198-- и Content-Length: xxxxxxxxx

-----------------------------8655433224198

Comment: @илья Content-Length: xxxxxxxxx  - Это количество байт в файле. Firmware data . -----------------------------8655433224198-- - это собственно содержание файла прошивки. boundary=---------------------------8655433224198 - является разделителем, для определения конца файла. Предполагаю что так. У вас один файл прошивки? или несколько?

Comment: один файл прошивки

Comment: а как передать  Firmware data ???

Comment: @илья, попробуйте указать полный путь к файлу в  data=@xxxxxx.bin" и имя в filename=\"xxxxxx.bin\""